# Does the choice of compiler and language affect Time Complexity?

Tags: algorithm, math, compiler-construction, time, time-complexity

When people speak about the time complexity involved with solving mathematical problems using computer science strategies, does the choice of compiler, computer, or language have an affect on the times a single equation might produce? would running an algorithm in assembly on an x86 machine produce a faster result than creating the same formula in java on a x64 machine?

Edit: this question sort of branches off from the original, if the choice of compiler and language don't matter, then is an algorithm itself the single determining factor of its time complexity?

Comment: Choice of compiler and language usually affects the constant factors, it does not affect time complexity (unless the compiler does deep magic and rewrites your algorithm).

Comment: Are you asking whether language and compiler choices affect the asymptotics/Big-Oh of a program or the actual runtime in cycles?

Comment: more so the asymptotics of a program

Comment: The time complexity/asymptotic behaviour is a property of the algorithm alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of asymptotic analysis is so that we don't have to consider the nuances introduced by varying compilers, architectures, implementations, etc. As long as the algorithm is implemented a way that follows the assumptions used in the time analysis, other factors can be safely ignored.

I'm primarily talking about non-trivial algorithms though. For example, I might have the code:

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){}
```

Standard analysis would say that this snippet of code has a runtime of `O(N)`. Yet a good compiler would realize that this is merely a nop and optimize it away, leaving you with an `O(1)`. However, compilers are not smart enough (yet) to make any asymptotically significant optimizations for anything non-trivial.

An example where certain analysis assumptions do not hold is when you don't have random access memory. So you have to be sure that your programming platform meets all these assumptions. Otherwise, a different analysis will have to performed.

Answer (score 1):

Except if you use some exotic language such as [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) which does not feature built-ins for common operations (+,-,/,*,…), time complexity does not depend on the language.

But space complexity depends on the compiler in case you use [tail-rec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) functions.